# how to fix CONVERSION errors after importing SSIS PROJECT

Tags: ssis, type-conversion

I'm importing a perfectly working SSIS project from TFS.

I have actually a problem with all the packages that contain a data FLOW with a date importation.

I get dozens of this error :

Validation error. DFT Get Date ODBC Source CodeDate2 [63]: The OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between types "DT_BYTES" and "DT_DBDATE" for "Date".

and when I click on the odbc source editor, I have the following message:

the metadata of the following output columnsdoes not match the metadata of the external columns with which the output columns are associated:

Output "ODBC Source Output": "Date"

Do you want to replace the metadata of the output columns with the metadata of the external columns?

the fact is that works everywhere  but on my computer.

is there an ole db provider component I'm lacking of something like that?

Comment: What is your ODBC source system? Do you have the ODBC driver for that system installed on your local computer?

Comment: @digital.aaron the driver for the source is SQL ANYWHERE 11, I just upgraded to 16 but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: On the SQL ANYWHERE side (your source), what is the native datatype of column that corresponds to the "Date" destination column? Also, what datatype is the destination column expecting?

Comment: i get Date with the sql command through a cast As date of a column in my table. and the destination column is expecting a date as well.

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading will work, but if that's not possible for you, then rewriting your queries may also solve your problem.

In my case I had a Postgres query returning columns of type *date*.  I just converted them all to *timestamptz* using `::timestamptz`.  At that point the columns changed from *DT_BYTES* to *DT_DBTIMESTAMP*, which was just fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the version of Visual Studio or SSDT.

Try to install SSDT 15.8.0([SSDT previous releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017#recent-downloads)), and run the package in it.

I once saw similar posts on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home?forum=sqlintegrationservices) after the release of Visual Studio 15.9.2

[Import from Teradata using ODBC gives VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/201b7caf-92f3-4088-bd35-0cae35e57796/import-from-teradata-using-odbc-gives-vsneedsnewmetadata-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

[ODBC Progress datatype problems after updating to VS 2017 15.9](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a7d219f1-89e6-403d-9feb-15d242f3483d/odbc-progress-datatype-problems-after-updating-to-vs-2017-159?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: thanks, I did a rollback to VS 15.5 and I don't get the pb anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I forced the type casting it in the select and it works :

```
SELECT
    [...]
    cast(release_date as datetime) as release_date,
    [...]
FROM cm_wo
```